# Load cursor with certain resolution

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

I have two cursor resources. The first one [IDC_CURSOR1] contains three different image types:

- 32x32, 24 bpp
- 48x48, 24 bpp
- 64x64, 24 bpp

The second one [IDC_CURSOR2] contains only one:

- 48x48, 24 bpp

If I'm calling LoadCursor(hInst, IDC_CURSOR1) it always loads 32x32 version and I was unable to find the way to load 48x48 or 64x64 version. In second case it loads 48x48 icon (because there is no other version), but it scales it down to 32x32.

**How can I load a cursor with other than 32x32 resolution?**

BTW: I tried to change DPI because according to msdn it should automatically load higher resolution cursor in higher dpi, but it doesn't.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `LoadImage` passing `IMAGE_CURSOR` and specifying the desired dimensions.

```
Cursor = (HCURSOR)LoadImage(hinst, IDC_CURSOR1, IMAGE_CURSOR, 64, 64, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
```

Comment: Thank you! MS API function names are so obvious :D

Comment: Have you read the documentation for LoadCursor? It directs you to LoadImage.

Comment: Ooops, I Didn't see that because it was mentioned in the beginning :)

Comment: Always worth reading docs from top to bottom

Comment: I always do that, but sometimes it has opposite effect when author tries to distinguish something and makes a portion of text looks different, i.e. it becomes "invisible"...